# Is there a better way to ignore the plural than "stem = TRUE" in a dfm?

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda

I am pre-processing my data to run an LDA model. I was wondering if there is a better way to ignore plurals (such as "rates", "rate", "contry", "countries") than using "stem = TRUE"? I don't want to stem all the words but only some specific words that appear frequently either plural or singular.

Any hint?

I tried with `"stem = TRUE"` and I also created a dictionary and used `"dictonary=dict"` in the dfm code but it obviously graps only the words of the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to use a tool to tag your plural nouns, and then to convert these to singular.  Unlike the stemmer solution, this will not stem words such as *stemming* to *stem*, or *quickly* to *quick*, etc.

I recommend using the **spacyr** package for this, which integrates nicely with **quanteda**.  Here's an example:

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.4.3

library("spacyr")

txt <- c(
  "Plurals in English can include irregular words such as stimuli.",
  "One mouse, two mice, one house, two houses."
)
txt_parsed <- spacy_parse(txt, tag = TRUE)
## Found 'spacy_condaenv'. spacyr will use this environment
## successfully initialized (spaCy Version: 2.1.3, language model: en)
## (python options: type = "condaenv", value = "spacy_condaenv")
txt_parsed
##    doc_id sentence_id token_id     token     lemma   pos tag     entity
## 1   text1           1        1   Plurals    plural  NOUN NNS           
## 2   text1           1        2        in        in   ADP  IN           
## 3   text1           1        3   English   English PROPN NNP LANGUAGE_B
## 4   text1           1        4       can       can  VERB  MD           
## 5   text1           1        5   include   include  VERB  VB           
## 6   text1           1        6 irregular irregular   ADJ  JJ           
## 7   text1           1        7     words      word  NOUN NNS           
## 8   text1           1        8      such      such   ADJ  JJ           
## 9   text1           1        9        as        as   ADP  IN           
## 10  text1           1       10   stimuli  stimulus  NOUN NNS           
## 11  text1           1       11         .         . PUNCT   .           
## 12  text2           1        1       One       one   NUM  CD CARDINAL_B
## 13  text2           1        2     mouse     mouse  NOUN  NN           
## 14  text2           1        3         ,         , PUNCT   ,           
## 15  text2           1        4       two       two   NUM  CD CARDINAL_B
## 16  text2           1        5      mice     mouse  NOUN NNS           
## 17  text2           1        6         ,         , PUNCT   ,           
## 18  text2           1        7       one       one   NUM  CD CARDINAL_B
## 19  text2           1        8     house     house  NOUN  NN           
## 20  text2           1        9         ,         , PUNCT   ,           
## 21  text2           1       10       two       two   NUM  CD CARDINAL_B
## 22  text2           1       11    houses     house  NOUN NNS           
## 23  text2           1       12         .         . PUNCT   .

# replace token with lemma for plural nouns
txt_parsed$token <- ifelse(txt_parsed$tag == "NNS",
  txt_parsed$lemma,
  txt_parsed$token
)
```

(Of course there are many ways to execute this conditional replacement, including **dplyr**.)

Now the words that are plural nouns have been replaced by their single noun variants, including the irregular ones such as *stimuli* and *mice*, which no stemmer would be smart enough to figure out.

```r
dfmat <- dfm(as.tokens(txt_parsed), remove_punct = TRUE)
dfmat
## Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 14 features (50.0% sparse).
## 2 x 14 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
##        features
## docs    plural in english can include irregular word such as stimulus one
##   text1      1  1       1   1       1         1    1    1  1        1   0
##   text2      0  0       0   0       0         0    0    0  0        0   2
##        features
## docs    mouse two house
##   text1     0   0     0
##   text2     2   2     2
```